# Mysql database insertion from form not working in cakephp using ajax

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Please help me. Thanks in advance. Actually i am trying to insert into mysql database from html form. My form contains users combo box with data from the database. When I am selecting the user from the combo box the corresponding courses assigned with text boxes and price textboxs to enter data will display, this i have done using ajax.
Now the situation is I am not able to insert data from the form into mysql database. I will explain everything step by step.

Inside UsersController.php page
The below function will display course textbox and price textboxes when clicking the users combobox from add_price.ctp view page

```
<?php

public function showprice()
   {
      $this->loadModel('Exam');   
      $id = $_POST['userid'];

      if($id!=0)   
      {  

         $allPrice = $this->Exam->query("select * from exams where username = $id");                  
        foreach($allPrice as $allPrices)
        {

         $total_price = $allPrices['exams']['exam'];                      
         $price = explode(',',$total_price);
         echo "<table class='tblrow' width='350px'>";     
         for($i=0;$i<count($price);$i++) 
         {

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><label for='Course'>Course</label><input type='text' id='course' name='data[Price][course][]' value='$price[$i]'></td>";
          echo "<td><label for='Price'>Price</label><input type='text' id='price' name='data[Price][price][]' value=''></td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";          
         }

        }

        echo "</table>";    

      }
      else 
      {
        echo "No results found";     

      }

       die();      

   }

The below function is for inserting into Mysql database from the form.

public function price_submit()   
  {

    // print_r($_POST);
     if(isset($_POST['data'])) 
     {

         $this->loadModel('Price'); 
         $priceData = $_POST['data'];
         //$this->set(array('priceData'=>$priceData,'_serialize'=>'pric‌​eData'));          
         $this->Price->create();
         $this->Price->save($priceData);   

         /*
         if($this->Price->save($priceData))  
         {

           echo "Data added successfully";                   

         } 
          */ 

         if($this->Price->save($priceData))   
         {
              //$this->Session->setFlash('<p style="width:220px;background-color:#34A853;color:white;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">User is Created Successfully</p>');       
              $this->redirect('index');     

         }


      }      

     $this->loadModel('User'); 
     //$userData = $this->User->find('all');    
     $userData =  $this->User->query("select * from users where id!= 15 and id!= 8");        
     $this->set('users',$userData);    


  }

  ?>

    My add_price.ctp page is 

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <?php echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.min.css'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui.min.js'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min'); ?>  

            <?php echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min'); ?> 

            <style type="text/css"> 


             #formadd{ width:550px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;margin: 0 auto;background-color:white;box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px } 
             #content{ padding:10px 0px 0px 84px;}
             #heading{ font-size:25px;padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;text-align:center; }
             .col-md-3{ width:400px;background-color:white;margin:10px 0px 20px 10px; } 
             .clearall{clear:both;}
             .error{color:#D06578;}  
            </style>

            <script>

    This code is for when selecting users from the combobox it will call the UsersController showprice function for displaying the courses and price textboxes.        



        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#user').change(function(){         
             var nameIdVal = $(this).val(); 
             $.ajax({

                   type: "POST",
                   url: '/invl_exams/showprice', 
                   cache: "false",
                   data: {userid:nameIdVal}, 
                   success : function(result){
                   //alert(result);
                   $('#divprice').html(result);                              

                   } 
              }); 

            });

          });



    This code will call price_submit from the UsersController.php to insert into database   



        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').click(function(event){
              event.preventDefault();         

                 $.ajax({ 

                        url: "/invl_exams/submitprice",
                        method: "POST",                     
                        data: $('#ExamAddExamForm').serialize(),   
                        dataType: "text",    
                        success: function(strMessage){ 
                          consloe.log(strMessage);          
                           //$('#msg').text(strMessage);  
                        },
                        error: function(strMessage){ 
                          console.log('error');          
                           //$('#msg').text(strMessage);   
                        } 


                     });     

                    clearData();     

            });

          });

          function clearData()
          {
            $('#ExamAddExamForm :input').each(function(){
               $(this).val('');   

            });

          } 

          </script>          
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="formadd">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="heading">Assign Price</p>

        <div id="content">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="msg"></div>

         <form name="priceForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="ExamAddExamForm"  action="/invl_exams/users/priceSubmit">  
         <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ExamUsername">Users</label>  
            <select class="form-control" required="required" id="user" name="data[Price][userid][]">    
             <option value="">-- Select --</option>
            <?php foreach($users as $username): ?>   
             <option value="<?php echo $username['users']['id']?>"><?php echo $username['users']['username']?>
             </option>
            <?php endforeach;  ?> 
            </select> 
            <label id="ExamUsername-error" class="error" for="ExamUsername"></label>       
          </div>

           <!--On selecting username showing the Courses with price textboxes in this id here -->  
           <div class="form-group" id="divprice"> 

           </div>

          <div class="form-group">  
            <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>  
          </div>
        </form>

        </div><br class="clearall">
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>

-------------- MY FULL CODE AS BELOW ------------------------------------

    My controller page is UsersController.php

    <?php
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    class UsersController extends AppController
    {
       public function showprice()
       {
          $this->loadModel('Exam');   
          $id = $_POST['userid'];
          //echo $id;
          //die();        
          if($id!=0)   
          {  

             $allPrice = $this->Exam->query("select * from exams where username = $id");
             //echo "<pre>";       
             //print_r($allPrice);
             //echo "</pre>";
             //echo count($allPrice);

             //print_r($allPrice[0]['exams']['exam']);  
             // die();         
            foreach($allPrice as $allPrices)
            {

             $total_price = $allPrices['exams']['exam'];                      
             $price = explode(',',$total_price);
             echo "<table class='tblrow' width='350px'>";     
             for($i=0;$i<count($price);$i++) 
             {
              //echo $price[$i];
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td><label for='Course'>Course</label><input type='text' id='course' name='data[Price][course][]' value='$price[$i]'></td>";
              echo "<td><label for='Price'>Price</label><input type='text' id='price' name='data[Price][price][]' value=''></td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";          
             }

            }

            echo "</table>";    

          }
          else 
          {
            echo "No results found";     

          }

           die();      

       }  


      public function price_submit()   
      {

        // print_r($_POST);
         if(isset($_POST['data'])) 
         {

             $this->loadModel('Price'); 
             $priceData = $_POST['data'];
             //$this->set(array('priceData'=>$priceData,'_serialize'=>'pric‌​eData'));          
             $this->Price->create();
             $this->Price->save($priceData);   

             /*
             if($this->Price->save($priceData))  
             {

               echo "Data added successfully";                   

             } 
              */ 

             if($this->Price->save($priceData))   
             {
                  //$this->Session->setFlash('<p style="width:220px;background-color:#34A853;color:white;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">User is Created Successfully</p>');       
                  $this->redirect('index');     

             }


          }      




      }  



    }
    ?>


My routes.php page is 

    <?php
    Router::connect('/submitprice', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'price_submit'));    

        Router::connect('/course', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'priceshow'));  
    ?>

My add_price.ctp page is

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.min.css'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui.min.js'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min'); ?>  

        <?php echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min'); ?> 

        <style type="text/css"> 
         /*body{background-color:#D4D6D3;}
         #formadd{ width:600px;height:700px;margin: 0 auto;background-color:white;}
         #heading{ background-color:#668CAF;width:600px;height:60px;font-size:25px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;}
         #content{ padding:10px 0px 0px 84px;} 
         .col-md-3{ width:400px;background-color:white;margin:10px 0px 20px 10px; } 
         .clearall{clear:both;} */

         #formadd{ width:550px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;margin: 0 auto;background-color:white;box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px } 
         #content{ padding:10px 0px 0px 84px;}
         #heading{ font-size:25px;padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;text-align:center; }
         .col-md-3{ width:400px;background-color:white;margin:10px 0px 20px 10px; } 
         .clearall{clear:both;}
         .error{color:#D06578;}  
        </style>

        <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ExamDateMonth").datepicker( { dateFormat: " yy-mm-dd " } );     
      });

      $(function() { 

        // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
        $("#ExamAddExamForm").validate({

            // Specify the validation rules
            rules: {
                ExamUsername:  { required: true },
                ExamName:  { required: true }

            },

            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages: {
                ExamUsername: "Please enter the Username",
                ExamName: "Please enter the Examname", 


            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });

      });

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#user').change(function(){         
         var nameIdVal = $(this).val(); 
         $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: '/invl_exams/userprice', 
               cache: "false",
               data: {userid:nameIdVal}, 
               success : function(result){
               //alert(result);
               $('#divprice').html(result);                              

               } 
          }); 

        });

      }); 

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();         
             //console.log($('#ExamAddExamForm').serialize()); 
             $.ajax({ 

                    url: "/invl_exams/submitprice",
                    method: "POST",                     
                    data: $('#ExamAddExamForm').serialize(),   
                    dataType: "text",    
                    success: function(strMessage){ 
                      consloe.log(strMessage);          
                       //$('#msg').text(strMessage);  
                    },
                    error: function(strMessage){ 
                      console.log('error');          
                       //$('#msg').text(strMessage);   
                    } 


                 });     

                clearData();     

        });

      });

      function clearData()
      {
        $('#ExamAddExamForm :input').each(function(){
           $(this).val('');   

        });

      } 

      </script>          
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="formadd">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="heading">Assign Price</p>

    <div id="content">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div id="msg"></div>

     <form name="priceForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="ExamAddExamForm"  action="/invl_exams/users/priceSubmit">  
     <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ExamUsername">Users</label>  
        <select class="form-control" required="required" id="user" name="data[Price][userid][]">    
         <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        <?php foreach($users as $username): ?>   
         <option value="<?php echo $username['users']['id']?>"><?php echo $username['users']['username']?>
         </option>
        <?php endforeach;  ?> 
        </select> 
        <label id="ExamUsername-error" class="error" for="ExamUsername"></label>       
      </div>

       <!--On selecting username showing the Courses with price textboxes in this id here -->  
       <div class="form-group" id="divprice"> 

       </div>

      <div class="form-group">  
        <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>  
      </div>
    </form>

    </div><br class="clearall">
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

My Model page is User.php

    <?php
    //App::uses ('AppModel','Model'); 
    class User extends AppModel{

      public $validate = array(
            'username' => array(

                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Username is required'
                ),
                'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'This username has already been taken') 

            ),        
            'password' => array(

                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'A password is required' 
                ),
               'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Password has already been taken')  
            ), 
            'full_name' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Full name is required' 
                )
            ),
            /*'role' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Role is required'   
                )
            ) */
           'email' => array(
           array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'massage' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
                 ),
              ), 
              'secondary_email' => array(
           array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'massage' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
                 ),
              ),      
          'phone' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Phone is required'  
                )
            ),
            'secondary_phone' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Phone is required'  
                )
            ),
            'location' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Loacation is required'  
                )
            ),
            'business_name' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Business Name is required'  
                )
            ),
            'document' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Document is required'  
                )
            ),
            'doc_file' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Document is required'  
                )
            ),
            'pname' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Name is required'  
                )
            ),
            'pemail' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Please enter a Valid Email Id'  
                )
            ),
            'pOfc_phone' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Please enter a Phone Number'  
                )
            ),
            'pdesignation' => array(
                'required' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notBlank',
                    'message' => 'Designation is Required'  
                )
            ),

        );

    } 


    ?>
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code, I really recommend you to do the blog tutorial of the CakePHP framework and become familiar with the very basics of the framework and then start over.

Comment: Accessing superglobals directly, avoiding the query builder, SQL injection vulnerabilities, duplicate save calls, generating output in a controller.. No offense, but you're using CakePHP totally wrong. edit: @burzum beat me to it. You really need to make yourself more familiar with how CakePHP works. Besides that, questions that are basically just "_doesn't work_", are considered offtopic on StackOverflow. Please be as specific as possible when describing problems, ie what exactly happens, what should happen instead, what have you tried to debug the issue, etc...

Comment: No I have seperate controller function and view page to display the form. I will edit my previous code , at the bottom you can find the controller page and view page.Please give me a minute

Comment: At the bottom i have written

Comment: You can see my full code I have mentioned below the dotted line ------- MY FULL CODE AS BELOW ----------------------